# pine script v4 : session range issue

Tags: session, range, pine-script

i am learning pine script and session with this original source code from tradingview : [Session and time information](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Sessions_and_time_functions.html)

```
//@version=4
study("Opening high/low", overlay=true)
highTimeFrame = input("D", type=input.resolution)
sessSpec = input("0930-1600", type=input.session)
//---
is_newbar(res, sess) =>
   t = time(res, sess)
   na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] < t
//---
newbar = is_newbar("1440", sessSpec)
//---
var float s1 = na
var float s2 = na
//---
if newbar
s1 := low
s2 := high
//---
plot(s1, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=color.red)
plot(s2, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=3, color=color.lime)
```

the problem is that it does'nt show the all session's range ; it only shows up the first bar's range whatever the timeframe is.

I need the all session's range.
How can i fix it please.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

**@PineCoders-LucF**

I have found source of yours. It's exactly what i want,
but the option :   squareBox = boxType == "Fixed levels" bugs.

the source code :

```
//@version=4
//@author=LucF, for PineCoders
study("Time Range", "", true)
sessionInfo = input("1100-1500", "Session")
boxType = input("Fixed levels", "Box Type", options = ["None", "Dynamic levels", "Fixed levels"])
showBg = input(false, "Show background")
squareBox = boxType == "Fixed levels"
dynamicBox = boxType == "Dynamic levels"
showBox = squareBox or dynamicBox

inSession = time(timeframe.period, sessionInfo)
invisible = #FFFFFF

loLevel = lowest(10)
hiLevel = highest(10)
var hi = 10e-10
var lo = 10e10
// When a new period begins, reset hi/lo.
if inSession and not inSession[1]
    hi := dynamicBox ? high : hiLevel
else
    if dynamicBox
        hi := max(high, hi)
if inSession and not inSession[1]
    lo := dynamicBox ? low : loLevel
else
    if dynamicBox
        lo := min(low, lo)

hiPlot = plot(showBox and inSession ? hi : na, "Highs", invisible)
loPlot = plot(showBox and inSession ? lo : na, "Lows", invisible)
fill(hiPlot, loPlot, color.navy)

// Plot background.
bgcolor(showBg and inSession ? color.blue : na)
```

EDIT :
[Bug of levels option picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU5A2.png)